# Gorm: failed to configure TLS (sslmode is invalid)

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to learn how to use gorm but faced with the small and silly problem. When I try to connect to my database, program throws me this error:

```
[error] failed to initialize database, got error cannot parse `host=localhost, user=postgres, password=xxxxx dbname=astra, port=5432, sslmode=disable, TimeZone=UTC`: failed to configure TLS (sslmode is invalid)
```

And tbh I don't know how to fix it and what can be the problem.

So here's my code:

```golang
func setupDb() {
    dsn := "host=localhost, user=postgres, password=postgres, dbname=astra, port=5432, sslmode=disable, TimeZone=UTC"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        logger_config.ErrorLogger.Println("Couldn't connect to database")
    }
}
```

So what can be the problem? If you know, please, tell me. I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: remove all commas from your connection string

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV Oh, yeah, my fault. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection string should be `host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres dbname=astra port=5432 sslmode=disable TimeZone=UTC`

Demonstrated [here](https://gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html#PostgreSQL) in gorm's documentation

This is actually one of the [formats PostgreSQL accepts for connection strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING-KEYWORD-VALUE).